# How to show mobile view within a desktop "dashboard" webpage?

Tags: html, css, mobile, desktop

I'm working on a project which would show a mobile webpage within a desktop view "dashboard".  The dashboard would provide some details regarding the mobile view.

My question is if I know the width and height of the mobile phone in question, how can I setup a DIV to show how it would show in that mobile phone?  I want to maintain everything exactly such as font-sizing and other css considerations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `css` @media rule, see: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

```
.show-desktop { display: block; }
.show-mobile { display: none; }

/* SMALLER THAN IPAD*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 1023px) { 
    .show-mobile {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .show-desktop {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting CSS handling.  How does this allow a DIV in a desktop webpage take on mobile characteristics while allowing the rest of the desktop webpage to be maintained as a desktop view?

Comment: You can set the DIV classes in a global scope, outside the media queries, so no matters the screen size it will always respect the parameters. I assume that your "dashboard" mobile DIV parameters are all inside @media queries..

Answer (score 0):

i think this can help you, https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/

```
 /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S3 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ashry.  I had seen these types of tags, but never used them.  Is there a way to use them specifically for a DIV within a desktop webpage so that the particular DIV takes on the mobile view/css?

Comment: maybe like this, <div class="demo"></div>, in the css: @media only screen and (min-device-width: 400px) { .demo { background: black; } }, look at the demo class in div, you can use Ctrl+shift+i, to see the mobile view perspective.

Comment: So, I wanted to do this without leaning on the browser alternate mobile views.  My hope was to have a desktop webpage with information and next to the information (on the same desktop webpage in browser), show an emulated mobile view.  So, I'm trying to mix device views with the mobile view being a child of the desktop view.  I hope that makes more sense.